# How do I return all values from JSON file to website?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am working on a little webshop project but ran into an issue. I am trying to print out every single product in the JSON file to my HTML but it only prints one. I got it to work in the terminal, but not when using Jinja so I am guessing something is wrong there.

Here is the python function:

```
@app.route('/testing')
def testing():
    with open('clothes/hoodies.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    
    for name in data['hoodies']:
        product_name = name['product-name'].splitlines()

    for price in data['hoodies']:
        product_price = price['price'].splitlines()

    for color in data['hoodies']:
        product_color = color['color'].splitlines()
    
    for image in data['hoodies']:
        img = image['image']
    return render_template('test.html', product_name=product_name, product_color=product_color, product_price=product_price, img=img)
```

Here is my HTML:

```
{% for name in product_name %}
<h1>{{ name }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
<!---->
{% for price in product_price %}
<h1>{{ price }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
<!---->
{% for color in product_color %}
<h1>{{ color }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
<!---->
{% for image in img %}
<img src="{{ image }}" alt="image" />
{% endfor %}
```

Here is a little part of the JSON file:

```
"hoodies": [
    {
      "product-name": "Reebok Classics fleece hoodie in green",
      "price": "54.95",
      "color": "Green",
      "image": [
        "link",
        "link",
        "link",
      ]
    },
    {
      "product-name": "COLLUSION Unisex hoodie in tie dye with print",
      "price": "25.00",
      "color": "Multi",
      "image": [
        "link",
        "link",
        "link",
      ]
    },
    {
      "product-name": "ASOS DESIGN organic muscle hoodie with split hem in brown",
      "price": "20.00",
      "color": "Tobacco brown",
      "image": [
        "link",
        "link",
        "link",
      ]
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currenty running loops, but actually you don't save each item in some structure, therefore it only keeps the last item of each loop. Try this instead (do the same for each loop):

Change this:

```
for name in data['hoodies']:
        product_name = name['product-name'].splitlines()
```

to this:

```
product_name=[name['product-name'].splitlines() for name in data['hoodies']]
```

Full code:

```
@app.route('/testing')
def testing():
    with open('clothes/hoodies.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    
    product_name=[i['product-name'].splitlines() for i in data['hoodies']]

    product_price=[i['price'].splitlines() for i in data['hoodies']]

    product_color=[i['color'].splitlines() for i in data['hoodies']]

    img=[i['image'] for i in data['hoodies']]

    return render_template('test.html', product_name=product_name, product_color=product_color, product_price=product_price, img=img)
```

Comment: Ahh I see. I tried this before but did not get it to work, have to read a bit about it and do some testing to learn it. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

You're re-defining the value of `product_name`, `product_price`, `product_color` and `img` rather than creating lists. Therefore, the value of these variables will only be the last item in the loop. You can do what @loaTzimas showed which is how I'd do it as it requires less code, or if you're unfamiliar with list comprehensions, you can do:

```py
product_name = []
product_price = []
product_color = []
img = []

for name in data['hoodies']:
    product_name.append(name['product-name'].splitlines())

for price in data['hoodies']:
    product_price.append(price['price'].splitlines())

for color in data['hoodies']:
    product_color.append(color['color'].splitlines())

for image in data['hoodies']:
    img.append(image['image'])
```